# How to send an single email for multiples jobs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

In my jenkins i have 2 different jobs, will be scheduled to call at 15 mins timelap. I am sending an separate emails for both the jobs with status.

I want to send an single email for both the jobs, once both jobs are get executed
Could some suggest me how to send 1 email for n number of jobs with each jobs status is noted in body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to trigger both jobs with a pipeline job something like (untested)

```
def resulta
def resultb
parallel a: {
   resulta = build 'joba'
}, b: {
   resultb = build 'jobb'
}
emailext body: "Joba: ${resulta.result} Jobb: ${resultb.result}", subject: 'Job Status', to: 'test@example.com'
```

Comment: Hello David, Thanks for the quick response, could you please provide the steps to do above solution

Comment: There is a job type called pipeline that allows you to use groovy code to perform the build see https://wiki.jenkins.io/x/z4N2B

Comment: I have tried with Pipeline job and try to execute above groovy code but still i am not able to build the jobs.

Comment: I think above script is not able to build the job

Comment: what happens when you try the above? (I just fixed an error)

Comment: Thankyou somuch...I can able to run both jobs and get the result of the jobs..:)

Comment: Earlier, I have used customized groovy template for separate email. Now, How can i use the same template in place of above of code.

Comment: emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html-custom.template"}''',
    subject: "Jobs Status",
    to: "abc@gmail.com"   This gives only current job(Pipeline Job) Result. How can i use the template to display the both sub jobs results and details.

Comment: You will have to make a custom template to do that it’s not designed for multiple jobs

Comment: In the above example, i can able to get results if joba or jobb is passed. I am not able to get result when any job is fail. And even any of the job is failed mail also not able to trigger. How can i get result even failed jobs as well. joba or jobb is failed i need to get result for both the jobs and mail need to trigger with both jobs results. ----Please help me on this...

Comment: build job: 'joba', propagate: false
see the built in documentation for the build step